# How do I create a bitmask to delimit the corrupted areas of the ram using the badram option of grub

Tags: boot, grub2, ram

I have a macbook air that has the ram memory soldered and the memory ranges corrupted starting from 0x784C1B10 (1924MB) (cpu in pararell mode, in a single cpu#0 or #2 the low memory error change to start from 0x10060AC50 (4102MB) and up to 0x1605F7518 (5637MB) and the memtest also indicates a Bits in Error Mask    00FF00FF00000000, The intermediate errors are approximate since memtest freezes when it reaches the errors and through trial and error I have come close to analyzing these areas of memory, I need the mask to enter the grub, applying an XNOR 0x50066240, 0x61000000 result on 0xfBf966240 it is this the mask?

GRUB_BADRAM="0x50066240,0xfBf966240"
[![memtest report][1]][1]
bits in errors shown by the memtest report image indicate 48 to 55 and 32 to 39

0000 0000 1111 1111 0000 0000 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
If change to Hex (same number as memtest results in bits in errors):
FF 00 FF 00 00 00 00
invert 0 to 1 with NOT:
1111111100000000111111110000000011111111111111111111111111111111
FF 00 FF 00 FF FF FF FF
thats look more as the mask, but is a number longer than the adress range... I do not understand.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwTnj.png

Comment: You have defective hardware what are you trying to do?

Comment: blacklist the faulty ram memmory with grub.

Comment: Grub has absolutely nothing to do with it. Grub is a bootloader, that's all.

Comment: "Filter out bad RAM. This command notifies the memory manager that specified regions of RAM ought to be filtered out (usually, because they’re damaged). This remains in effect after a payload kernel has been loaded by GRUB," https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/badram.html

Comment: You even can tested in your computer with out faulty RAM i am doing that to find the correct mask, I am testing GRUB_BADRAM="0x10060AC50,0xff0f0ff" and after boot if you check the black list with: sudo grep RAM /proc/iomem  
When I compare with out it I get more System RAM Used but is not just on top of the adress 0x10060AC50 even in lower memory is asigned:
> 00067000-0009ffff : System RAM
...
> 10067000-20065fff : System RAM
> 100067000-110065fff : System RAM
> 110067000-120065fff : System RAM
...
> 250067000-260065fff : System RAM
> 260067000-26effffff : System RAM